# Historical Stock Prices of delisted company

Tags: historical-data, yahoo-finance, google-finance

With services like Google Finance or Yahoo Finance it is very convenient to find the historical stock price metric of a listed company, but if the company is not listed, I can't find the data.

For example, I want to see the price metrics for Lawson Software, which had been listed  on NASDAQ (LWSN). How could I find its historical price metrics?

Answer (score 3):

For those on a budget, check if your local library has access to / or a copy of the "Standard & Poor's Daily Stock Price Record". Access to that or a similar service may be available as part of your library patronage. If not available it may be available at your metropolitan central library.

Comprehensive stock pricing data which provides adjustments for splits, mergers, capital distributions and other relevant events is still a premium product.

External link to New York Public Library blog post on subject:
http://www.nypl.org/blog/2012/04/09/finding-historical-stock-prices

Answer (score 0):

You need a source of delisted historical data. Such data is typically only available from paid sources.

According to my records, Lawson Software Inc listed on the NASDAQ on 7 Dec 2001 and delisted on 6 Jul 2011.  Its final traded price was $11.23.  It was taken over by Infor who bid $11.25 per share.

Source: Symbol LWSN-201107 within Premium Data US delisted stocks historical data set available from http://www.premiumdata.net/products/premiumdata/ushistorical.php

Disclosure: I am a co-owner of Norgate / Premium Data.